# understanding decode_cf argument to xarray.open_dataset

Tags: python-xarray

I'm starting to learn xarray and am reading the documentation. The description for the `decode_cf` argument to `xarray.open_dataset` in the  [current documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_dataset.html) is

> decode_cf:bool, optional
>
> Whether to decode these variables, assuming they were saved according to CF conventions.

What variables is this referring to? I'm unable to figure it out from context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is referring to whether the variables stored in the file have metadata stored in the CF convention or not. CF stands for Climate and Forecast. From [Unidata](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/conventions.html) page for NetCDF conventions:

> The conventions for CF (Climate and Forecast) metadata are designed to promote the processing and sharing of files created with the NetCDF API. The CF conventions are increasingly gaining acceptance and have been adopted by a number of projects and groups as a primary standard. The conventions define metadata that provide a definitive description of what the data in each variable represents, and the spatial and temporal properties of the data. This enables users of data from different sources to decide which quantities are comparable, and facilitates building applications with powerful extraction, regridding, and display capabilities.

For more [info](http://cfconventions.org/).

Comment: So 'these variables' is 'the variables stored in the file'. Thanks @Light_B.